# How to set timeouts of db calls using flask and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to set timeout of db calls, and I looked into SQLAlchemy documentation http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/config/

There are many configuration parameters, but never illustrate an example of how to use them. Could anyone show me how to use SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT in order to set timeout of db calls? I have them in my .py files, but I don't know whether I use the parameter correctly.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["LOGGER_NAME"] = ' '.join([app.logger_name, 
socket.gethostname(), instance_id])
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = config.sqlalchemy_database_uri
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT"] = 30
```

The document only states that "Specifies the connection timeout for the pool. Defaults to 10." and I don't even know the unit of this 10, is it seconds or milliseconds?

Answer (score -1):

The unit is seconds.  As can be seen in the later documentation.  [Configuration — Flask-SQLAlchemy Documentation (2.3)](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/)